# Navigate from a razor page to a XAML page - .NET Maui Blazor Hybrid

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, maui-blazor

I am currently attempting to use the Camera.MAUI library. This requires me (as far as I can tell) to use a Xaml page instead of a razor page. I created a ContentPage from the visual studio templates and made the page. It currently looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Camera.MAUI;assembly=Camera.MAUI"
             x:Class="Sample.Wtf.LoyaltyApp.StoreApp.Components.Pages.Scan"
             Title="Scan">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <cv:CameraView x:Name="_cameraView" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="200"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I have attempted to navigate to the page using these two methods, which both did not work.

```
@onclick='() => NavigationManager.NavigateTo( "/Scan" )'
@onclick='async () => await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync( new Pages.Scan() )'
```

Ideally I would like the render the Xaml component in my razor page, but I'm beginning to think that this isn't possible.

I have also already tried using [XamlForBlazor](https://xaml-for-blazor.com/) and would rather not use that as I have to pay for it.

TL;DR

How can I navigate from a razor page to a Xaml page without changing my entire project to use Xaml.

Answer (score 0):

I should have been using `PushAsModalAsync` instead of `PushAsync`