How can I display both a XAML view and a Razor component within a Blazor page?
I have a Blazor page (Home.razor) where I want to display a heading from the Razor component and also include a XAML view that displays a message, such as "Hello from XAML". How can I achieve this integration so that both the Razor and XAML content are rendered together on the same page?
Home Razor page
@page "/my-blazor-page"

<h3>Hello from Blazor</h3>
<XAMLPage>

XAMLPage

<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Hello from XAMLPage"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
           FontSize="24"
           TextColor="Black"/>
</StackLayout>


You might want to review the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77847904/navigate-from-a-razor-page-to-a-xaml-page-net-maui-blazor-hybrid?rq=2.  I have some XAML pages, that I just converted to a Razor Component

You can't add XAML components in a Razor page as that is all HTML and CSS. However, you can do the opposite through a BlazorWebView. Then you can add a Blazor component and mix that with other .NET MAUI controls.
You can also mix .NET MAUI XAML pages together with your Razor pages in the form of a popup, bottom sheet or just navigate there as a full page.
I go over this in more detail in this video.

Thank you, @Gerald! A few days ago, I was watching your video about navigation on YT.

Thanks for watching! Let me know if you need anything!

I do have a question if you don’t mind. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78921433/how-to-navigate-between-blazor-pages-in-a-net-maui-blazor-app-when-the-destinat?noredirect=1#comment139194725_78921433

https://github.com/MoeezAgha/TabIssueRedrect.git
